# Touchpad toggling on and off upon login

Tags: gnome, login, touchpad, synaptics

I have a quite annoying problem with my touchpad on Ubuntu.

When I log in, the touchpad keeps toggling on and off. The toggling stops immediately when I press a key on my keyboard. Sometimes it becomes Enabled and sometimes Disabled. It seems like it's about timing. If it becomes disabled, I have to synchronize the FN+F3 (Touchpad toggle) with the physical toggle button. To clarify, this means that I have to make sure that both the keyboard touchpad setting is enabled and the physical as well.

This is just a flaw that I would like to correct if it's possible. It happens every time I have had the lid closed. If I just lock the computer or restart it without closing the lid, the touchpad works as expected. I have Ubuntu 14.04 right now, but it was also present on my 13.04 installation, but the toggling was a lot quicker there. I'd say it toggles about every 0.2 seconds now. This is not present on my Windows installation (dual boot). I have not found any questions regarding this on the forum. Please inform me if I have left out any important details.

#### System specifications

- Ubuntu version: 14.04 LTS (Also in 13.04)
- Window Manager: Gnome 3.8 (GDM)
- Touchpad brand: Synaptics
- Drivers: Proprietary
- Laptop brand: MSI Ge60 0NC